# Can AWS be used an SAML Identity provider?

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I know that AWS IAM supports integration with external SAML providers (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_saml.html) and Cognito is its Federated Identity Provider but I wanted to know whether AWS Cognito/ IAM can used as an SAML IDP to other applications

Comment: Does anyone has answer to this?

Comment: At the moment AWS Cognito does not act as an SAML IDP.It can only act as a RP.But it can be added in future as many users have requested this usecase

Comment: It is a duplicate but my question was asked before the other one and I had some interactions with AWS cognito team as well at Reinvent conference were this questions got answered.I forgot to update it.Thanks for pointing out

Comment: @AbhijeetKushe was the second comment the answer from AWS team? Also, were you able to get Cognito as SAML IdP?